# LINQ: multiple Where calls only uses last one?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm trying to get a query going that will search multiple tags. The tags are db based and I've related them to the entity with a junction table. If I search with 1 tag, I get the correct results, but if I search with 2 tags, I only get the entities that match the second tag.

Here's the C# code that builds the IQueryable:

```
  var awTable = db.Artworks.Where( aw => true );  //default get all

  awTable = awTable.Where( aw => (bool)aw.IsArtworkVisible  );


  foreach ( SearchTag tagToMatch in tagList )
                {

                    awTable = awTable.Where( aw => aw.ArtworkName.Contains( tagToMatch.SearchTagText )
                                               || db.SearchTag_x_Artworks.Where( stxa => stxa.SearchTagID == tagToMatch.SearchTagID )
                                               .Select( stxa => stxa.ArtworkID ).Contains( aw.ArtworkID ) );


                }
```

Here's the resulting SQL, which, if I plug it into a query window and set the parameter values, includes both where clauses and returns the correct list of entities. (WTF!?!?)

```
    {SELECT [t0].[ArtworkID], [t0].[ArtworkName], ... [t0].[MediumID]
FROM [dbo].[Artworks] AS [t0]
WHERE ((EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[SearchTag_x_Artwork] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[ArtworkID] = [t0].[ArtworkID]) AND ([t1].[SearchTagID] = @p0)
    )) OR ([t0].[ArtworkName] LIKE @p1)) AND ((EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[SearchTag_x_Artwork] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[ArtworkID] = [t0].[ArtworkID]) AND ([t2].[SearchTagID] = @p2)
    )) OR ([t0].[ArtworkName] LIKE @p3)) AND (([t0].[IsArtworkVisible]) = 1)
}
```

This is kind of befuddling, any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's really befuddling is why you do some things:
`var awTable = db.Artworks.Where( aw => true );  //default get all`

...wat

Comment: I tried to leave out an if statement for clarity:

 var awTable = db.Artworks.Where( aw => true );

            if ( !isAuthenticated )
            {
                awTable = awTable.Where( aw => (bool)aw.IsArtworkVisible  );
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with the way C# handles captured variables in **closures** like your lambda expressions.

Your capturing the same variable `tagToMatch`. Please try this:

```
  foreach ( SearchTag tagToMatch in tagList )
  {
        SearchTag localTagToMatch = tagToMatch;
        awTable = awTable.Where( aw => aw.ArtworkName.Contains( localTagToMatch .SearchTagText )
                                               || db.SearchTag_x_Artworks.Where( stxa => stxa.SearchTagID == localTagToMatch .SearchTagID )
                                               .Select( stxa => stxa.ArtworkID ).Contains( aw.ArtworkID ) );
  }
```

Please read [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Holy crap that works! Thanks! Thanks for the link as well, as it's not really obvious that there's something going on like the last SearchTag is where all of the Where lambdas get their parameter values from, so I'm going to have to read up on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var awTable = db.Artworks.Where( aw => (bool)aw.IsArtworkVisible );  //the first was unnecessary

foreach ( SearchTag tagToMatch in tagList )
{
    awTable = awTable.AndAlso(aw => 
        aw.ArtworkName.Contains(tagToMatch.SearchTagText) ||
        db.SearchTag_x_Artworks.Where(stxa => stxa.SearchTagID == tagToMatch && stxa.ArtworkID == aw.ArtworkID);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, my version of LINQ doesn't have the AndAlso. I'll have to look for that and see if I can download it.